# How to do Laravel Eloquent multiple joins with conditions properly?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to convert an old php code to Laravel and I came across a complicated query statement with a lot of joins and conditions. I tried converting the query statement (see 2nd image), but the results I am getting is different. The total rows for original code returns 13,340 rows, when I tried executing the laravel version, I was getting a `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41553920 bytes)` due to the rows being so many which probably means that there is something wrong with the query I made.

Original PHP Code:[image]

Eloquent Version: [image]

Comment: if you do `->toSql()` at the end of that query builder query you can see the SQL query that's actually generated so you can check where the discrepancy is. My guess is the `where` inside the `on` callback.

Comment: How come you're using a ton of joins instead of using models & defining relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JOIN on `t_client` requires a nested constraint:

```
->join('t_client AS fc', function($join) {
    $join->on('t_client.shop_id', '=', 'fc.client_id')
        ->where(function($where) {
            $where->where('fc.client_div', '=', '0')
                ->orWhere('fc.client_div', '=', '3');
        });
})
```

You can also use `whereIn()`:

```
->join('t_client AS fc', function($join) {
    $join->on('t_client.shop_id', '=', 'fc.client_id')
        ->whereIn('fc.client_div', '=', ['0', '3']);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel eloquent you can also define relationships, so you could define a user as having a rank, and after you could use the laravel query builder to actually get those results (without using JOINS yourself)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

If this is not what you need, I would suggest doing what @apokrvfos suggested and using ->toSql() to find out where your query goes wrong